# JAXB One object with several propOrder

Tags: java, jaxb

I have an object like this :

```
public class Data {  
    protected String field1;  
    protected String field2;  
    protected String field3;

    public getField1(){
        return this.field1;
    }

    public getField2(){
        return this.field2;
    }

    public getField3(){
        return this.field3;
    }

    public setField1(String field){
       this.field1 = field;
    }

    public setField2(String field){
       this.field2 = field;
    }

    public setField3(String field){
       this.field3 = field;
    }
}
```

And i would like use it with 2 different propOrder :

- **@XmlType(propOrder = { "field1", "field3", "field2" })**
- **@XmlType(propOrder = { "field3", "field2", "field1" })**

I'm trying to do it using 2 new classes :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder = { "field1", "field3", "field2" })
public class DataOne extends Data {  

}
```

and

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder = { "field3", "field2", "field1" })
public class DataTwo extends Data {  

}
```

This solution doesn't work, i am doing something wrong but what ?

The thing i know that i coulp create 2 classes instead of extending one but in fact i have an object with 50 fields and i would like use 13 different propOrder to display them in an XML file.

I tried to find the same issue on the web without success... somebody has an idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: And the question/problem is?

Comment: That it doesn't work. I'm doing something bad.

Comment: You should post your MCVE and explain which exceptions your are gettion or which result you expect and don't get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I used those annotations on the parent and i use an asbract class instead of a class.

```
@XmlTransient
@XmlSeeAlso({ DataOne.class, DataTwo.class })
public abstract class Data {
    ...
}
```

Using this architecture i have two objects **DataOne**, **DataTwo**, with the same attributes but with a different order in the XML.

I imagine that it exists a proper way to do it, but this solution works fine for me.